# What does this represent?

Tags: computer-puzzle

> #actions /* 0,1,0,0 */
>
> .words /* 0,0,1,0 */

---

**Hints:**

Hint 1:

> It's a coding language.

Hint 2:

> The two lines are snippets that won't work on their own.

Hint 3:

> It's a stylesheet language.

Hint 4:

> It's CSS.

Hint 5:

> It relates to an aspect of CSS which many people find confusing.

Hint 6:

> The numbers in the comments are there to help you, but they merely make other stuff more obvious.

Hint 7:

> Why was the BEM naming convention created?

Hint 8:

> It's about specificity.

Comment: Actions speak louder than words... and as for Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) specificity, ID's (#) trump over class (.)....

Comment: @zipzit Oh dear, that was too easy. Do you want to post that as an answer?

Comment: Gcampbell the actions and words gave it away. I didn't understand any of the coding, but that's a very common phrase

Comment: @Inazuma You guys don't have a sandbox like on PPCG?

Comment: Honestly, I would have given fewer hints....  but it was still a great first time ever posting.

Comment: @zipzit I was inspired by [the hints](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/articles/3tmVKGc4dR463kWs0gT1SGT/game-hints) to the H2G2 game.

Comment: Certainly space the hints out. They're generally reserved for meting out bit by bit if a puzzle remains unsolved for a past-reasonable length of time (e.g. #1 after several hours, #2 the next day, #3 later on that day...).

Comment: @feelinferrety Ok, thanks for clarifying that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actions speak louder than words...

As for Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) specificity, ID's(#) trump over class(.) identifiers.  Here's a [reference.](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/#article-header-id-0)

[image: CSS Specificity Rankings]